# ready to use dynamic pie chart in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am evaluating to change the graphics I generated so far using highcharts.js to d3.js

just for fun and I want to learn how d3.js works.

I wonder if there is something similar to the url below (see if you click on a pie it gives you new data), something dynamic and ready  to use (or not to implement from zero).

What I wanna achieve, more or less...

http://lully.snv.jussieu.fr/gbif/mapping/graphs/examples/pie-legend.htm

thanks in advance

Pere

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to replace Highcharts, I think the only good open-source alternative available at the moment is Bob Monteverde's Novus charts library: http://novus.github.com/nvd3/. NVD3 has a nice pie chart and also has good legends. Take a look at all the charts from this library and you will see what I mean. You can also find a good pie chart in Stephen Boak's tutorial: http://blog.stephenboak.com/2011/08/07/easy-as-a-pie.html. Another interesting option is to look for Frank Guerino's questions on the D3 js google group. I would use NVD3 if I were you. It might need some adjustments, but it seems to be the best option currently. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Simple function to generate Pie Charts utilisiing d3.js. This function is part of the http://xhprof.io/ project. It is able to handle datasets of arbitrary size. It has several options that allow for customisation, such as the label margin, circle radius and visibility of the percentage data (refer to the source code).

[image]

The demo is available at https://dev.anuary.com/858b33b7-bd66-507b-a9f1-533e4de79ba3/. The source code is available at https://github.com/gajus/pie-chart.